# Typescript syntax to loop through types -- let type Types = typeof myObject[number]

Tags: typescript, syntax, redux

Very hard to find information since I don't know what this is called and can only tell what it's doing from context. It's used on this example at the bottom.

https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#typing-reducer

```
// inferring union type of actions
import { $call } from 'utility-types';
import * as actions from './actions';
const returnsOfActions = Object.values(actions).map($call);
export type TodosAction = typeof returnsOfActions[number];
```

Specifically the last line. `number` in not defined but it appears to loop through the array `returnOfActions`. Basically is this equivalent to doing

```
export type TodosAction = ActionType1 | ActionType2 | ...
```

and what would you call this type of syntax (so I can read more)

Comment: `number` is also a type, it's saying *"things that are the type of thing a numerical index would get from this array"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also intrigued by this syntax . Turns out this is what you call a lookup type. It's best explained in the annoucement blog of Typescript 2.1 [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/12/07/announcing-typescript-2-1/#keyof-and-lookup-types).

In your case things are much easier to understand if we explicitly write out the type,

- write out the type

  ```
  interface Actions {
    [index: number] = ActionType1 | ActionType2
  }
  ```
- explicit type declaration here

  ```
  const returnsOfActions: Actions = Object.values(actions).map($call);
  ```
- What this says is to get the type which is indexed by number. Which
  in our case is  `ActionType1 | ActionType2`

  ```
  export type TodosAction = typeof returnsOfActions[number];
  ```